# Does the following matrixpowers converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, convergence-divergence

> Given a $3\times 3$ Matrix:
>   $$A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
> -2 & -16.8 & -16.8& \\
> -1 & -4.8 & -5.8 \\
> 1.4 & 8 & 9\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Determine whether the powers $A^n, n=1,2,3...$ converges and if so unto which Matrix?

Since I haven't got any theory behind Matrix convergence I simply entered the Matrix into Mathmatica and tried various high powers. I found that at around $n=10$ and above the bottom two rows stay fixed at integers while the top row changes. But my answer is incorrect it seems. What am I doing wrong?

*My answer:*
$$\begin{bmatrix}
DNE & DNE & DNE\\
-1 & -4 & -5 \\
1 & 4 & 5\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A particular matrix you had, with eigenvalues $1, 0.8, 0.4$.

You reduce it to a diagonal form 
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & -16.8 & -16.8\\
-1 & -4.8 & -5.8 \\
1.4 & 8 & 9
\end{array}\right]= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.8 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.4
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
so the sequence of powers 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0.8^n & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.4^n
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$converges  to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -6 & -7 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & -4 & -5 \\
1 & 4 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
$$
your answer.

Comment: Thanks alot! Now I get it :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have any theory behind, let me give you some.

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $3\times 3$ matrix with complex entries and assume it is diagonalizable.

There exist scalars (the eigenvalues) $\lambda _1, \lambda _2, \lambda _3$ and an invertible $3\times 3$ matrix $P$ such that $$A=P\begin{bmatrix} \lambda _1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda _2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}.$$

The sequence $\left(A^n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges if, and only if $\left(\begin{bmatrix} \lambda _1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda _2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}^n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges.

Furthermore, if any of them converges, one has $$\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(A^n\right)=P\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}\left(\begin{bmatrix} \lambda _1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda _2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}^n\right)P^{-1}.$$

Since for all natural numbers $n$ one has $$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda _1& 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda _2 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda _1^n& 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda _2^n & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3^n\end{bmatrix}$$ it suffices to analyze the converge of the real sequences $\left(\lambda _i^n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, with $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ and these converge if, and only if, $|\lambda _i|<1$ or $\lambda _i=1$.

You should now be able to answer your question.

This argument is easily generalizable to matrices of any order.

Comment: @Strange Brew This answer can be extended to non-diagonalizable matrices, if you know about jordan normal form. If you do, let me know and I'll expand my answer.

Comment: Okay, this seems really useful. I haven't learned about jordan normal form yet.

I'll have to read up on eigenvalues. Could you maybe provide a simple example of your reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I solved it myself. The issue was that the top row actually converges unto $0$ not that they do no exist as I had answered.

The solution is thus:

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
-1&-4&-5\\
1&4&5\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$